# Keep secondary axis when changing chart filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have three metrics to display.
One of them has to be on a secondary axis, and the secondary axis gets wiped out every time I change the filter.

I thought I could use a `Worksheet_Change` event so that whenever the filter is changed a line of code changes the `.AxisGroup` property to 2 for that metric.

How do I capture the change of the `PivotItems.Visible` property?
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Okay well I ran to stack overflow too soon. I was able to figure out a workaround myself so I'll post it here. Can't promise it's pretty!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim pvtfield As PivotField
Dim cnt As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim srs As Series
Dim index As Long

Worksheets("Brand Pivot Table").ChartObjects("Turn By Date").Activate
cnt = ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Brand").PivotItems.Count
For i = 1 To cnt
    If ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Brand").PivotItems(i).Visible = True Then
            index = 1
            For Each srs In ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection
                If InStr(srs.Name, "Turnover") <> 0 Then
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(index).AxisGroup = 2
                End If
                index = index + 1
            Next srs
    End If
Next i
```